# Access uploaded image in Sails.js backend project

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-404, sails.js, assets, image-uploading

I am trying to do an upload and then accessing the image. The upload is going well, uploading the image to assets/images, but when I try to access the image from the browser like http://localhost:1337/images/image-name.jpg it gives me 404. I use Sails.js only for backend purposes - for API and the project is created with --no-front-end option. My front end is on AngularJS.

My upload function:

```
avatarUpload: function(req, res) {
    req.file('avatar').upload({
        // don't allow the total upload size to exceed ~10MB
        maxBytes: 10000000,
        dirname: '../../assets/images'
    }, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
        console.log(uploadedFiles);
        if (err) {

            return res.negotiate(err);
        }

        // If no files were uploaded, respond with an error.
        if (uploadedFiles.length === 0) {

            return res.badRequest('No file was uploaded');
        }

        // Save the "fd" and the url where the avatar for a user can be accessed
        User
            .update(req.userId, {

                // Generate a unique URL where the avatar can be downloaded.
                avatarUrl: require('util').format('%s/user/avatar/%s', sails.getBaseUrl(), req.userId),

                // Grab the first file and use it's `fd` (file descriptor)
                avatarFd: uploadedFiles[0].fd
            })
            .exec(function (err){
                if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
                return res.ok();
            });
    });
}
```

I see the image in the assets/images folder - something like this - 54cd1fc5-89e8-477d-84e4-dd5fd048abc0.jpg

http://localhost:1337/assets/images/54cd1fc5-89e8-477d-84e4-dd5fd048abc0.jpg - gives 404

http://localhost:1337/images/54cd1fc5-89e8-477d-84e4-dd5fd048abc0.jpg - gives 404

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the resources your application accesses are not accessed directly from the `assets` directory but the `.tmp` directory in the project root.

The assets are copied to the `.tmp` directory when sails is lifted, so anything added after the lift isn't present in `.tmp`.

What I usually do is upload to `.tmp` and [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11295106/1100528) the file to `assets` on completion. This way `assets` isn't polluted in case the upload fails for any reason.

Let us know if this works. Good luck!

**Update**
Found a relevant [link](http://nickholdren.com/2014/11/20/uploading-files-in-sails-js/) for this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to do an upload and to access the picture following the tutorial you provided. It really helped me. Just one small thing to note - when copying the uploaded file from assets to `.tmp` folder, if the folder structure - `.tmp/public/images/uploads` there is not present, we need to create it first or `fs` error breaks the application if not caught.

Comment: Indeed! You can use the [mkdirp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp) module or [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) (for added functionality) to create a folder if it doesn't exist using a single command. Or just use this [well-reasoned solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21196961/1100528).