# Node fsmkdirSync error

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

Inside of `CacheModule.js` i have the following code:

```
    socket.on('saveUserCache', function (obj, user_id) {
    var jsonOutput = JSON.stringify(obj);
    if (!fs.existsSync('./cacheObjects/' + user_id)) {
        fs.mkdirSync('./cacheObjects/' + user_id, 0777, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
    fs.writeFile('./cacheObjects/' + user_id + '/cache.json', jsonOutput, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('It\'s saved!');
    });
});
```

The idea behind this is to check if the users folder exists (if not) create a new folder and then write to a file.

However im getting the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir './cacheObjects/125'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:794:18)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/project/app_server/costum_modules/CacheModule.js:10:16)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:172:7)
at Socket.onevent (/var/www/project/app_server/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:330:8)
at Socket.onpacket (/var/www/project/app_server/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:290:12)
at Client.ondecoded (/var/www/project/app_server/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:193:14)
at Decoder.Emitter.emit (/var/www/project/app_server/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:134:20)
at Decoder.add (/var/www/project/app_server/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:247:12)
at Client.ondata (/var/www/project/app_server/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:175:18)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at Socket.onPacket (/var/www/project/app_server/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/socket.js:99:14)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:169:7)
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening. it looks like its sending mkdir with the string. Also i have given the right permissions (so it is not lacking permissions)

Comment: `./cacheObjects/` is not an absolute path.

Comment: have you tried `'../cacheObjects/'`?

Comment: @Joum tried it same error

Comment: I'm talking a bit out of my ass here, but to me it looks like it's searching for the dir you specified in the same place the script is, not in the parent dir. Could that be it?

Comment: As `fs.existsSync` is deprecated, check out this answer, might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4482701/24098

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/a/21196961/24098