# Bluebird promise is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm using node 4.5+ and bluebird. I have the following code I intend to use with `then`:

```
var checkdir = function(directory) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.statAsync(directory).then(function() {
            resolve(true);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            if(err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                fs.mkdirAsync(directory).then(function() {
                    resolve(true);
                }).catch(function() {
                    reject(new Error('Can not create folder'));
                });
            } else {
                reject(new Error('Unknown fs stat error: ' + err));
            }
        });
    });
};
```

`Async` functions are from `fs-extra-promise` module. However, when I try to use this function, I get `Unhandled rejection Error: Unknown error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

Calling:

```
                checkdir(dir).then(function() {
                    ...
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    reject(new Error('Unknown error: ' + err));
                });
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: That's weird, your code runs find in a snippet without bluebird. How do you implement the library?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: Any indication (stack trace) of which `.then` the error is referring to?

Comment: @Tomalak not sure what you mean but feel free to edit and fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any kind of "exists" check in filesystem operations is [actively discouraged](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) in the node documentation. (Whether you do the exists check with `stat` or with `exists` is irrelevant.)

That means, in addition to Benjamin Gruenbaum's comment regarding [the improper use of promises in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) in your code, there is another important point to make:

The right way to create a directory is by calling `mkdir` unconditionally and ignoring `EEXIST` (compare [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21196961/18771) for more context).

```
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(fs);

var ensureDir = function ensureDir(path) {
    return fs.mkdirAsync(path).catch((err) => { if (err.code !== 'EEXIST') throw err; });
}
```

You can use [the `mkdirp` module](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp) to create a path recursively, like `mkdir -p` would.

Comment: I've changed code but still getting an error: `Unhandled rejection Error: Unknown error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. Can it be another promise rejection?

Comment: There is no `.then()` in my code, so the you see error has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I had another promise spoiling the return result for whole chain. Thank you!