# `fs-extra` integrate with `bluebird ` got `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` error

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird, fs-extra

Here is my code

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fse = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs-extra'));

fse.remove('./myDir').then(function () {
  console.log('Remove myDir done.')
});
```

I always get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` error.

Version:

```
node: v6.9.2
bluebird: 3.4.7
fs-extra: 1.0.0
```

I searched and found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39446644/bluebird-promise-is-undefined) but not exactly quite the same, and I tried that answer, unfortunately, it can't solve my problem.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: It's my fault, I forgot to add `Async`-suffix to `fse.remove` method, the correct way should be `fse.removeAsync`, please see [here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/features.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct way is `fse.removeAsync`,  add `Async`suffix to `fse.remove`, please see bluebird API [here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/features.html). Hope it can help others.

**Update:**

With the latest `fs-extra`, I don't need to import `bluebird` anymore.
See [here](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/remove.md), below syntax works well.

```
// Promise Usage
fs.remove('/tmp/myfile')
.then(() => {
  console.log('success!')
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error(err)
})
```