# Node.js' __dirname & __filename equivalent in Deno

Tags: node.js, path, deno

How can I get the directory & file name of the current module?. In Node.js I would use: `__dirname` & `__filename` for that

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Since Deno 1.40 you can now use `import.meta.dirname` and `import.meta.filename`

---

**OLD ANSWER**

In Deno, there aren't variables like [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) or [`__filename`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_filename) but you can get the same values thanks to [`import.meta.url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta)

On *nix (including MacOS), you can use `URL` constructor for that (won't work for Windows, see next option):

```js
const __filename = new URL('', import.meta.url).pathname;
// Will contain trailing slash
const __dirname = new URL('.', import.meta.url).pathname;
```

**Note**: On Windows `__filename` would be something like `/C:/example/mod.ts` and `__dirname` would be `/C:/example/`. But the next alternative below will work on Windows.

---

Alternatively, you can use [`std/path`](https://deno.land/std/path), which works on *nix and also Windows:

```js
import * as path from "https://deno.land/std@0.188.0/path/mod.ts";

const __filename = path.fromFileUrl(import.meta.url);
// Without trailing slash
const __dirname = path.dirname(path.fromFileUrl(import.meta.url));
```

With that, even on Windows you get standard Windows paths (like `C:\example\mod.ts` and `C:\example`).

---

Another alternative for *nix (not Windows) is to use a third party module such as [`deno-dirname`](https://deno.land/x/dirname):

```
import __ from 'https://deno.land/x/dirname/mod.ts';
const { __filename, __dirname } = __(import.meta);
```

But this also provides incorrect paths on Windows.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Windows, I found a working solution here: https://morioh.com/p/68bf0c73b2bb

Comment: Not working on Windows either - it generates paths with an incorrect leading space like `/C:/path/to/file.json` which `readTextFile` cannot understand.

Comment: @AndrewKoster At least now it works.

Answer (score 3):

This is the up-to-date fix that `just works` on all platforms as far as I can tell and provides complete feature parity:

```
import * as path from "https://deno.land/std@0.207.0/path/mod.ts";

const __filename = path.fromFileUrl(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(path.fromFileUrl(import.meta.url));
```