# Multer is not uploading a file to the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I am trying to upload a file to a server via Multer. All this code does is it creates the folder  but not the file. I also tried to use a tutorial on github but no luck either
My code on **frontend**

```
<p class="font-weight-bolder mb-3">Upload Screenshot
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data"></form><input id="uploadFile" type="file" name="image" />
</p>
```

The code **AJAX**

```
$('#uploadFile').on('change', function(){
  var file = $(this).get(0).files[0];
  console.log(typeof file);
  console.log(file)
  console.log(file.name)
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('Upload', file, file.name);
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action') || window.location.pathname + '/repr_screenshot',
    type: "POST",
    data: file,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){
      console.log("success")
    },
    error: function(data){
      console.log("file not uploaded")
    }
  });
})
```

And the **MAIN.JS**

```
var multer  = require('multer')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: 'views/repr/mixin/screenshots',
  filename: '/file.png'})

var upload = multer({storage: storage,
  onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
    console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...')
  }
});

router.post('/repr_screenshot', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.file);
  return false;
})
```

The console.log output I get from frontend:

`Object`

`File {name: "Capture.PNG", lastModified: 1597907180050, lastModifiedDate: Thu Aug 20 2020 10:06:20 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 89172, …}`

`Capture.PNG`

And the output of console.log(req.file) is "Undefined"

Answer (score 0):

`destination` and `filename` both properties should be function. docs reference [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, "views/repr/mixin/screenshots");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.originalname);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single("image");


router.post("/repr_screenshot", (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.end("error file uploading");
    }
    res.status(200);
  });
});
```

Let me know if there any issue.

**UPDATE:** The destination folder should be existed before uploading.

I have change the `.single('file')` to `.single('image')` as your fieldname.

Comment: It doesn't give any issues, however, still won't upload the file and now even does not create a folder

Comment: Please check the updated code. And you have to create the destination folder beforehand, as per the docs. If you want dynamically created folders, you can use the packege  mkdirp or fs. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194934/how-to-create-a-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist-using-node-js

Comment: I've created the folder and changed 'file' to 'image' but unfortunately the issue still remains