# Can this If statement be written in one line?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

Is there a one line way of doing a if statement that only fires once with a boolean?

```
var boolean;    
if (!boolean) {
        function doSomething();
        boolean = true;
}
```

Something in the lines of this.

Comment: why do you want to write in one line?

Comment: @RBarryYoung My good man, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194934/how-to-create-a-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist-using-node-js#comment110333161_48436466

Comment: Code does not make any sense, why is there `function`?

Comment: It can be converted to a single line - just remove anything except `function doSomething();` and you're just left with the syntax error.

Comment: `function doSomething();` is invalid. Do you want to declare a `doSomething` function or execute it?

Comment: You might want to provide more context, e.g. how `boolean` is supposed to be read. It's useless in this tiny example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the [logical OR assignment `||=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment) with a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

```
boolean ||= (doSomething(), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not make much sense to do it as one line since the code is clear the way you have it written (minus your syntax error), but it can be done

```js
function test(myBool) {
  function doSomething () { console.log('run'); }
  myBool = myBool || doSomething() || true;
  console.log(myBool);
}

test(false);
test(true);
```

or if doSomething returns a true boolean or truthy value

```js
function test(myBool) {
  function doSomething () { console.log('run'); return true; }
  myBool = myBool || doSomething();
  console.log(myBool);
}

test(false);
test(true);
```

Comment: if `doSomething` returns a falsy value like `NaN`, it will set that value to `myBool`

Comment: I think `myBool = myBool || !doSomething() || true` ensures it always returns `true` irrespective of what `doSomething` returns