# Error: Command failed: convert: unable to open image - Node, express, imagemagick

Tags: javascript, image, node.js, express, resize

I'm trying to resize images before serving them to the client. Inside my public directory I have the directory `images`.  All images are being served to different pages successfully with unique permalinks. `http://localhost:3000/post/`+`permalink`.   I npm installed gm, imagemagick, and tried brew install imagemagick as well.  I have this in my routes files:

```
        var p = 'post/'+permalink
        console.log(p);
        var fs = require('fs');
        var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });

        gm('images/black-yellow-simple-lady-woman.jpg')
        .resize(234, 567)
        .autoOrient()
        .write(p, function (err) {
          if (err) console.log(' noooo! '+err);
        });




 Error: Command failed: convert: unable to open image `images/black-yellow-simple-lady-woman.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2643.
convert: no images defined `post/ribs_52977588145822' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3127.
```

Comment: What's the directory structure of your project? You can try calling `gm()` with the absolute image path.

Comment: The path was incorrect.  I needed to add public.  i'm deeply ashamed of myself.

Comment: I just had a similar 'embarrassing' situation: I was trying to save the image to 'public/images/folder_1/image.png', however, 'folder_1' didn't exist and hence I was getting your error. With this comment I am just trying to emphasise the importance of checking that the entire path is valid. In relation to this, see the following module which can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13696975/1972495

Answer (score 2):

Please change your relative path gm('images/black-yellow-simple-lady-woman.jpg') to absolute '/home/user/meteorproject/public/images/black-yellow-simple-lady-woman.jpg'