# NodeJS - mkdir possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know if its somehow possible to create folders on a local server with a node js application and than upload some stuff. Or if thats impossible. If its not possible directly with node, is there another method how I could solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you check the Node.js documentation? http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_mode_callback

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696148/node-js-create-folder-or-use-existing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `fs.mkdir`: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_mode_callback

There is a module for recursively creating directories called `mkdirp`: https://www.npmjs.org/package/mkdirp

Were there not API bindings for these operations, you could have instead used the `ChildProcess` built in module to spawn a subprocess to do the actual directory creation.

Answer (score 1):

Node has a file system API with good documentation.

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html