# ENOENT: no such file or directory: NODE JS

Tags: node.js, shell, filesystems, fs

Can someone help with this problem, I know that there are a lot of questions related to this problem but I have tried almost everything, nothing helps.

```
makeFile(dirName, fileName, content, callback) {
        if (!fs.existsSync(dirName)) {
            // fs.mkdirSync(dirName, {recursive: true});
            shell.mkdir('-p', dirName);
        }
        zlib.inflate(Buffer.from(content), (err, InfoInflated) => {
            if (err) {
                logger.error(err);
                return callback({ success: false, code: 500, err: err});
            }
let file = fs.createWriteStream(dirName + fileName, {
                    flags: 'a'
                });
            file.on('open', fd => {
                file.write(InfoInflated.toString('utf8'));
                file.end();
            }).on('error' , (err) => {
                logger.error(err);
                return callback({ success: false, code: 500, err: err});
            }).on('finish', () => {
                logger.info("file is complete !");
                return callback({success: true, code: 200, result: {message: "OK", file: dirName + fileName}});
            });
        });
    }
```

/tmp/files/2019-02-05/1205_undefined_undefined/1205_undefined_undefined.zip' this is the full path which creates an error

Comment: Please add some description about what you are doing and what is failing for the purpose of better understanding.

Comment: `fs.createWriteStream(dirName + fileName, ...` - please [edit] your post and show us the values of `dirName` and `fileName`. Also show us where exactly in your code the error gets raised.

Comment: @Corion I have edited the question

Comment: @Ashvin777 I have edited the question

Comment: Again, how do you call the `makeFile` function? Please show us a [mcve] so we can try to replicate your situation. The value of `dirName` and `fileName` are likely important, as is whether the directories you have in `dirName` already exist. If they don't all exist, `createWriteStream` will fail with `ENOENT` (which is `file or directory not found`).

Comment: Corion makeFile is called asynchronously, the dirName ( is  '/tmp/file' + moment(Date.now()).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '/',   fileName can be differ from it it is generated depending on some condition

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using shell syntax incorrectly. Also you may not need to use shell for creating the directory as it can be done using fs component itself.

Take a look at the solution for your script - https://jsitor.com/fh3IyKq74

It is executing you code and also showing the response properly. In `mkdir` make sure you should check empty string first actually firing that.

Comment: I have used fs sytem but , it did not  help, if you have suggestion I will be glad to see it :)

Comment: If you want more details you can take help from this ticket as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696148/node-js-create-folder-or-use-existing

Comment: Is this the error you are talking about `(node:98) [DEP0025] DeprecationWarning: sys is deprecated. Use util instead.
{ success: false,
  code: 500,
  err:
   { Error: incorrect header check
       at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:155:17) errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR' } }`